How to get subclass of a blender class
How to get all subclass of a bpy.data classes
The subclasses of bpy.types.Texture are:
BlendTexture, CloudsTexture, DistortedNoiseTexture, ImageTexture, MagicTexture, MarbleTexture, MusgraveTexture, NoiseTexture, StucciTexture, VoronoiTexture, WoodTexture

But in Blender 4.2, it only outputs one:
import bpy

for cls in bpy.types.Texture.__subclasses__():
    print(cls.__name__)
    
# >>>> ImageTexture

bpy.types.Texture.bl_rna_get_subclass_py("???")


You can get all subclasses by using this script. In this example, we retrieve all subclasses of bpy.types.Texture:
import bpy

def find_subclasses(base_class):
    subclasses = []
    for cls_name in dir(bpy.types):
        cls = getattr(bpy.types, cls_name)
        if isinstance(cls, type) and issubclass(cls, base_class) and cls is not base_class:
            subclasses.append(cls)
    return subclasses

texture_subclasses = find_subclasses(bpy.types.Texture)

for cls in texture_subclasses:
    print(cls.__name__)

It seems that after executing the above script, it triggers Blender to fully load and initialize those types. Which will then make your script work as well:
for cls in bpy.types.Texture.__subclasses__():
    print(cls.__name__)


Great, it works.
